# Validating a tuple

Tags: typescript

I have a type `Job`

```js
const days = ['Monday', 'Wednesday'] as const
type Day = typeof days[number]

const isValidDay = (value: string): value is Day => value in days

const statuses = ['start', 'end'] as const
type Status = typeof statuses[number]

const isValidStatus = (value: string): value is Status => value in statuses

type Job = [Day, Status]
```

I want to write a function to validate an argument conforms to type `Job`

Given I will use this validator like so

```js
const main = (value: string) => {
  const job = value.split('/')
  if (!isValidJob(job)) {
    throw new Error('Not a job')
  }

  // ...
}
```

I would think `isValidJob` should be implemented something like

```js
const isValidJob = (value: Array<string>): value is Job => {
  return value.length === 2 && isValidDay(value[0]) && isValidStatus(value[1])
}
```

But the following does not flag up any issues even though this validator does not assert that `value` conforms to `Job`, nor will `value[1]` ever be a number

```js
const isValidJob = (value: any): value is Job => {
  return typeof value[1] === 'number'
}
```

So my question is, how should I validate `job` is type `Job`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function which returns a type predicate only requires that a boolean be returned at runtime. That's just how they work - you are asserting that the validation provided is correct for that particular type. Your initial implementation of `isValidJob` looks like it will do this just fine. You could add an `Array.isArray` check if you wanted to type the `value` argument as `any` or `unknown`.

However, I don't think the previous two guards are correct. The [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) returns true for object properties and array indexes, not for elements in arrays. For instance:

```
isValidDay("Monday") // false
isValidDay("length") // true
isValidDay(0) // fails TS check but returns true
```

You could handle this with the `Array.some` method instead:

```
const isValidDay = (value: string): value is Day => days.some(d => d === value);
```

Comment: I assumed that Typescript would check my validation makes sense for the Type. Thanks for explaining, and pointing out the issues with the other functions!